# FF's divisors (calculate number of divisors of product of divisors of given number)

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

This is a problem from some online competition, but it's over now so i would like to know how to actually solve it.

> You are given number n and it has some (for number 4 you have 1,2,4) divisors (1 and itself included). If p is equal to product of all divisors of given number n find number of divisors of p.

I tried to solve it but my solution was just optimized brute force so i am looking for fast solution with math background.

Comment: What are constraints for n and p? It's easily solved in O(sqrt(n) + sqrt(p)).

Comment: 1 <= n <= 10^7  if you need to test it i found same problem in caribbean online judge https://coj.uci.cu/24h/problem.xhtml?pid=2849&lang=en

Comment: See [Is it okay to just ask for an algorithm to a problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271842/is-it-okay-to-just-ask-for-an-algorithm-to-a-problem). In addition, this is a computer science problem rather than a programming problem, so you'd better ask it in [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @АндрейМоскаленко no need for `sqrt(p)`, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at an example: `105`

`105` has 8 divisors:

```
1, 3, 5, 7, 15, 21, 35, 105
```

The number of divisors of the product of the divisors is `105^(d(105) / 2)`. We can easily see this by pairing each of the divisors:

```
1, 3, 5, 7, 15, 21, 35, 105
a  b  c  d   d   c   b   a

=> a*a * b*b * c*c * d*d
```

meaning we get `105` multiplied by itself `d(105) / 2` times.

Now let's look at the prime factors of `105`:

```
3, 5 and 7
```

We will have `d(105) / 2 = 4` of each of them in the product of the divisors:

```
3*3*3*3 * 5*5*5*5 * 7*7*7*7
```

In how many ways can the above multiplicands be combined?

```
5 ways to set 3
5 ways to set 5
5 ways to set 7

5 * 5 * 5 = 125
```

The product of the divisors of `105` has `125` divisors.

General formula:

```
f(n):
  d = product(map (\x -> x + 1) prime_counts)
  m = d / 2
  counts = map (\x -> m * x + 1) prime_counts

  return product(counts)
```

Random example:

```
f(63):
  d = product([3, 2]) = 6
  m = 6 / 2 = 3
  counts = map (\x -> m * x + 1) [2, 1] = [7, 4]

  return product([7,4]) = 28
```

The product of the divisors of `63`, `1 * 3 * 7 * 9 * 21 * 63 = 250047` has `28` divisors.

Answer (score 0):

I think this task is based on the following facts:

1. If some number `A` is factorized as `P1^N1*P2^N2*...*Pk^Nk`, then total number of divisors of `A` is `(N1+1)*(N2+1)*...*(Nk+1)`. It is easy to see why this is true: each prime divisor `Pi` can be in any power from `0` to `Ni`.
2. If `D` is a divisor of `A` than `A/D` is also a divisor of `A`

So you start with factorizing `n` and calculate total number of its divisors - lets call it `T`. Also it is important to check whether `n` is a perfect square or not (i.e. whether all its `Ni` are even).

Now when you have a factorization of `n` you need to get a factorization of `p`. Obviously all the prime factors will be the same and only powers will be different. You can calculate the powers basing on the facts #1 and #2. If you group all the divisors of `n` into pairs `D` + `n/D` you can notice that each pair after multiplication produces exactly `n`. The only exception might be if `n` is a perfect square and then `sqrt(n)` = `n/sqrt(n)` so there is no pair. In any case you may see that `p` is exactly `n^(T/2)`. (Note: `T` is odd only if all `Ni` of `n` were even i.e. if `n` was a perfect square.)

So it means that to get powers of factorization of `p` you should just multiple all powers of factorization of `n` by `T/2` and then calculate total number of divisors of `p` using the formula from the fact #1 again.

I expect that the longest part in this algorithm should be factorization of `n` which is a well studied problem. The rest should be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one algorithm. This may be improvable but that would take more time and thought.

Let's assume that `n = p^e * N`, where `p` is prime, `e` (for "exponent") is a positive integer, and `N` is not divisible by `p`. (I.e. `p^e` is in the canonical prime decomposition of `n`.) Then if we say that `N` has `c` factors (c for "count"), namely `f1, f2, ..., fc`, whose product is `P`, then the factors of `n` are

```
 1  * f1,  1  * f2, ...  1  * fc
 p  * f1,  p  * f2, ...  p  * fc
...
p^e * f1, p^e * f2, ... p^e * fc
```

Then the product of the first row is `1^c * f1 * f2 * ... * fj` which is just `P`. The second row has the product `p^c * f1 * f2 * ... * fj` which is `p*c * P`. The last row has the product `(p^(e))^c * f1 * f2 * ... * fj` which is just `p^(e*c) * P`. If we let `T(e)` be the `e`th triangular number, namely `1 + 2 + ... + e` then the product of all those factors of `n` is

```
p^(c * T(e)) * P^(e+1)
```

The shortcut to calculating `T(e)` is `e * (e+1) / 2`. The shortcut to calculating `c` is to use all the prime factors of `N` and their exponents `e1, ..., ek` in the prime factorization of `N`  so `c = (e1 + 1) * ... * (ek + 1)`. Those two shortcuts are well-known in number theory.

So here is an algorithm in pseudo-code.

```
# Find the prime factorization of the product of the factors of n
c = 1
set factor-list and exponent-list to empty lists
for each prime factor p of n:
    # Update the prime factorization of the product of factors
    e = the exponent of p in the prime factorization of n
    multiply each exponent in the exponent-list by e + 1
    append p to the factor list
    T = e * (e+1) / 2  # the e'th triangular number
    append c * T to the exponent-list
    # Update the number of divisors of the current product of factors
    c = c * (e+1)
# Find the number of divisors of the final product
result = 1
for each x in the exponent-list:
    result = result * (x + 1)
return result
```

I wrote a function in Python 3.6 to test the algorithm, and this checks up to `n = 10000`. (That value is low because the checking function is much slower than the function I am checking.) The algorithm was slightly changed, and the code to find the next prime divisor of `n` is simpler but slower than necessary.

```
def cnt_divisors_of_prod_of_divisors(n):
    """Return the count of the divisors of the product of the divisors
    of n
    """
    # Find the prime factorization of the product of the divisors of n
    num = n  # number to find prime factorization
    cnt = 1  # number of divisors of prime-factorization of n already done
    divisors = []  # prime divisors of product of divisors of n
    exponents = []  # their exponents in the product of divisors of n
    p = 1  # a fake prime divisor of n
    while num > 1:
        # Find the next prime divisor of n
        p += 1
        while num % p:
            p += 1
        # Find the exponent of that prime divisor
        e = 1
        num = num // p
        while num % p == 0:
            e += 1
            num = num // p
        # Multiply each exponent in the exponent-list by e + 1
        for j in range(len(exponents)):
            exponents[j] *= e + 1
        # Append p to the divisor list
        divisors.append(p)
        # Append the new exponent of p in the product to the exponent-list
        T = e * (e+1) // 2  # e'th triangular number
        exponents.append(cnt * T)
        # Update the number of divisors of n
        cnt *= e + 1
    # Find the number of divisors of the final product
    result = 1
    for x in exponents:
        result *= x + 1
    return result
```

That code on my machine for `n = 10**7` takes 6.03 microseconds, though that time depends greatly on the value of `n`. That seems acceptable!